# Python: Shell error gets saved in text file during error handling

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to python and I don't have much experience in programming. I am trying to create a script in python using the subprocess and os modules which, when executed, will open the command prompt and ask the user for the name of the WiFi and then the script will create a text file in which it will save the profile output. It is working perfectly by saving the profile output in a text file but the problem is, when the user enters invalid data, it saves the error itself in the text file which I want to display in the command prompt.

```
import subprocess
import os


def get_wifi_name():
    os.system('color A')
    os.system('cls')
    profile = input("\n[-]Enter name of previously connected WiFi: ")
    output = subprocess.getoutput('netsh wlan show profile ' + profile + ' key=clear')
    return profile, output


profile_name, output_content = get_wifi_name()

if output_content == "Profile " + profile_name + " is not found on the system.":
    os.system("\nPlease enter valid WiFi Network")
else:
    f = open('WiFi.txt', 'w')
    f.write(output_content)
    f.close()
```

Comment: os.system is obselete and you should move everything to subprocess. subprocess.communicate will return the usual result and error message separately and you will have better control of them

Comment: `os.system("\nPlease enter valid WiFi Network")` should be either `os.system("echo Please enter valid WiFi Network")` or `print("\nPlease enter valid WiFi Network")`

Comment: You should just check if `is not found on the system` appears in `output_content`. `if "is not found on the system" in output_content: …`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add **double quotes** here:

if output_content == 'Profile `"' + profile_name + '"` is not found on the system.':

**This should work:**

```
import subprocess
import os

def get_wifi_name():
    os.system('color A')
    os.system('cls')
    profile = input("\n[-]Enter name of previously connected WiFi: ")
    output = subprocess.getoutput('netsh wlan show profile ' + profile + ' key=clear')
    return profile, output


profile_name, output_content = get_wifi_name()

if output_content == 'Profile "' + profile_name + '" is not found on the system.':
    print("\nPlease a enter valid WiFi Network")
    input("\npress <enter> to exit")
else:
    f = open('WiFi.txt', 'w')
    f.write(output_content)
    f.close()
    print("\nFile saved successfully")
    input("\npress <enter> to exit")
```

Comment: we used `print()`, because `os.system()` will evaluate the **first** word from the given string as a **command**, and the string begins with "please", which is not a command in `cmd`, also, we used `input()` after printing something, because the cmd will **auto-shutdown** if no other commands are being executed (in case of running python files), if my answer **worked** for you, please consider `accepting` it :D